# When no input is provided, what is stored in the variable that accepts the input?

Tags: python

When no input is provided, what is stored in the variable that accepts the input?  I thought it would be `None`, so I write a test for it like:

```
foo = input('plz enter smthing')
if foo is None:
    print('plz enter again')
```

However, nothing is printed.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not `None`, it's `''`. An empty string. You can still use `if not foo`, though.

Answer (score 0):

input function takes string Type as input. For example:

```
>>> foo = input('plz enter smthing')
plz enter smthing
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
>>> foo
''
```

You can see that when you are not providing any input, it still shows you the Type str and right now, the value for foo is `''`.

Answer (score 0):

The old input function evaluates the string.

This is a huge problem (replace ... with your favorite command):

```
"__import__('os').system('...')"
```

So I think a better answer is: Don't use "input" in python 2.x

raw_input() returns a string. If you want an int for example:

```
int(raw_input())
```

This is fixed in python 3: raw_input() was renamed to input().